# How to measure packet count and sizes on Raspi Zero WH running buster

Tags: raspbian-buster

My ISP says I have too many devices on my wifi network at home and it could be causing performance issues.  **Bunk**!  What tools are available for a Raspi Zero WH running buster, headless that can report the number and size of packets the pi sends and receives during a given interval -- lets say 20 minutes.  I want each pi to monitor its own network volume.

I saw references to tcpdump, but that seems to be more for analyzing packets.  I just want them counted and weighed.

Four of my devices have DHT22 sensors that report the results to an Adafruit server once per minute.
Another runs a query once per day to download 1MB+/-.
Another runs an app on demand that downloads <<1MB each time it's run.
Then there's the handful of traffic from my ssh sessions to edit python code, git commits, etc.

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant.  Neither can I fathom why an ISP would question what is on your LAN.  They are only interested in traffic going through their network.

Comment: @joan, They really didn't question the device.  They just asked "How many devices".  I said 9 -- (2 phones, 2 laptops, Smart TV, 6 Pi Zeros).   They said "too many".  ty btw

Comment: Thats normal if you have any LAN OR WAN issues - I had a visit from the EE support team due to having 17 device and issues - took 6 months to argue my case by using lan and wan monitors to provide down was when items where not connected.  Changed router to one with diags to show exchange was not allowing password to EE servers in the end.  You need to get ISP to say what is max throughput their router NOT LINE supports in Kbs via wifi and LAN then put ALL traffic through Pi (inc Wifi) to prove issue - I bought new router and AP to stop issue in the end and junked ISP crap kit.

Comment: I would change question to ask what are good LAN / WAN / Wifi monitors to run on a Pi and use current notes are background as to why else question will get closed as it is nothing to do with the Pi :-)

Comment: @Andryroo.  thx.  Q rephrased.

Comment: *"I saw references to tcpdump, but that seems to be more for analyzing packets. I just want them counted and weighed"* -> Counting and weighing is a form of analysis, lol.  Tcpdump has a bit of a learning curve but is well suited to the task, which in this case is pretty simple so you won't have to learn much curve.  Note that doing this on a WPA encrypted network requires the monitoring device to be connected before everything else (or at least, everything that you want to analyze packets from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick overview you can show the statistics of an interface with, for example:

```
rpi ~$ ip -stats -stats link show wlan0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:7f:38:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    25097241   281838   0       0       0       0
    RX errors: length   crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    34492878   281896   0       0       0       0
    TX errors: aborted  fifo   window heartbeat transns
               0        0       0       0       2
```

More details you can find at:

```
rpi ~$ ls /sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/
collisions     rx_crc_errors   rx_frame_errors   rx_over_errors     tx_carrier_errors  tx_fifo_errors
multicast      rx_dropped      rx_length_errors  rx_packets         tx_compressed      tx_heartbeat_errors
rx_bytes       rx_errors       rx_missed_errors  tx_aborted_errors  tx_dropped         tx_packets
rx_compressed  rx_fifo_errors  rx_nohandler      tx_bytes           tx_errors          tx_window_errors

rpi ~$ cat /sys/class/net/wlan0/statistics/tx_packets 
300409
```

The only issue is that you cannot reset these counters without unloading the networking driver. They are all read-only. But with some little bash scripting this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this will work perfectly for my purpose.